# Sql Compact Drop all foreign keys

Tags: sql, key

How can I drop all foreign keys in my database?

I know how to get all foreign key names.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
```

Comment: build up your drop statement concatenatign constraint name and the appropriate drop command. if more help is needed just post your code.

Comment: How to loop through the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS table?

Comment: Just build up an alter table statement, like:
    SELECT 'alter table '+TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME+'drop constraint '+CONSTRAINT_NAME+char(10)+'go' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
IT will generate the list of alter statements that you can copy from the result pane and execute.

Comment: Note that + is product specific version of concat. || is the ANSI SQL way.